# How to pass parameter to similarity script function while querying

Tags: elasticsearch

In pair matching , formula 2*no.of pairs matched/union of pairs*100

ex: santhoshi is in elastic indexed document value and santhosh is searchin element in query then no.of pairs in santhoshi = 8,no.of pairs matched = 7,no.of pairs in santhosh = 7

```
result = 2*7/(7_8)*100 = 93%......
```

I tried below code which getting filed .sumDocFreq is "type":

> illegal_argument_exception,"reason": "Variable [field] is not defined."

Code:

```
{ "query": {
        "function_score": {
             "query": {
              "match": {
                "Name":"santhosh"
              }
            },
             "min_score":100,
            "functions": [
                {
                    "script_score": {
                         "script": {
                        "params" : {
                            "inputpairlength": 6 },
                        "source": "double tf = doc.freq; double ttf = field.sumDocFreq;  return (2* tf /(params.inputpairlength + ttf)) * 100;"
                         }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }

}

 "settings": {
      "similarity": {
      "scripted_tfidf": {
        "type": "scripted",
        "script": {
          "source": "double tf = doc.freq; double ttf = field.sumDocFreq;  return  tf / (params.inputpairlength+ttf) * 100;"
        }
      }
    },
```

getting param.input is not defined

I need to pass parameter and calculate score using  this

```
double tf = doc.freq; 
double ttf = field.sumDocFreq;  
return  tf / (params.inputpairlength+ttf) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the wrong way of accessing field statistics. Field statistics are accessed -

_index['FIELD'].docCount()

You can read more about it here - [Elastic Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/modules-advanced-scripting.html)

Comment: Thank u ..... one more doubt ....my requirement is need for current field in current document,not for all documents...,I want to get value of  no.of pairs(bi-gram) formed in Name field example "santhoshi" - 8,from  which attribute i can get it

Comment: you can index the number of bi-grams in a separate field, during the indexing of the document. ES won't give you bi-gram counts. Or else, you can just use doc['Name'].value.length()+1 as the number of pairs

Comment: that would be doc['Name'].value.length()-1 !!

Comment: I tried this  doc['Name'].value.length(), my doc[Name] ="santhoshi" but getting  doc['Name'].value.length() = 2,please suggest any other value

Comment: is your field text or a keyword? because this is giving me correct results. Which version of ES are you using ? Also, is the 'Name' field a single string or an array of strings ?

Comment: "Name": {
                    "type":     "text",
                    "analyzer": "bigrams" ,
                    "similarity": "scripted_tfidf",
                     "fielddata": true
                },

Comment: You should be using keyword  type for this field as you are anyways using function_score for scoring the docuements. Still, if you want a text field, you can make a new field as keyword and store the values as keyword in this field. from mapping perspective you can define "name_keyword":{"type":"keyword", "copy_to":"Name"}. This should do the job.

Comment: field type keyword can't support analyzers?

Comment: no, that's why suggested to keep 2 fields, one with keyword and one with text. 
text fields are analyzed whereas keywords are not. Also, as per your mapping which you shared, enabling fielddata for analyzed fields (text), is not a good idea as it eats up a lot of memory. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html